Dynamic rendering in Nextjs showing page not found
I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://nextjs.org/learn-pages-router/basics/dynamic-routes/implement-getstaticpaths
It basically says to add this folder structure:
pages/posts/[id].js

Then on the file [id].js I should impement getStaticPaths, getStaticProps and a component.
The example uses js while my app is ts, and I also want another path so I have changed the structure to: pages/slang/[id].tsx
And inside [id].tsx i have this:
"use client";
import { getAllPostIds, getPostData } from "../../../libs/slangs";

export default function Post({ slangData }) {
  return (
    <main>
      <p>{slangData.word}</p>
    </main>
  );
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const paths = getAllPostIds();
  console.log({ paths });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
}

type paramsT = {
  params: {
    id: string;
  };
};

export async function getStaticProps({ params }: paramsT) {
  const slangData = getPostData(params.id);
  return {
    props: {
      slangData,
    },
  };
}

Then i define getPostData and getAllPostIds like so:
const slangData = [
  {
    word: "Güey",
    description: "Dude",
    id: "guey",
  },
  {
    word: "Neta",
    description: "",
    id: "",
  },
];

export function getAllPostIds() {
  // Returns an array that looks like this:
  // [
  //   {
  //     params: {
  //       id: 'yolo'
  //     }
  //   }
  // ]

  console.log({ slangData });

  return slangData.map((slang) => {
    return {
      params: {
        id: slang.id,
      },
    };
  });
}

getAllPostIds();

export function getPostData(id: string) {
  const slang = slangData.filter((x) => x.id === id);

  return {
    id,
    ...slang,
  };
}

But when I go to http://localhost:3000/slang/guey it doesnt find any page.
What could be wrong? It seems to me that I am doing the same as in the tutorial.
